Can you finish my riddle dear? Or will the answer remain unclear?
In the shadows where secrets dwell,
A brilliant mind, a tale to tell.
From France he came, with wisdom deep,
In silent halls, his secrets keep.
His name obscured by time's cruel hand,
A method born in a distant land.
Numbers shift and letters turn,
In darkness, hidden truths discern.
He left this world in years long past,
Subtract his age, the die is cast.
Twice the years he lived in youth,
Reveal the name, unlock the truth.
Within these lines, a secret lies,
A darker path, where silence cries.
Seek the key, the master plan,
Unveil the name of this wise man.
- Nolan Nygma

It could be Blaise de Vigenère a French cryptographer.

It is possible, use his name,
As a code, unlock the game.
Hidden truths within your sight.
Between the lines, find what's right.
A new riddle is soon to come.
Use in tandem, the two become one.

@NolanNygma I just saw your new puzzle. I think I know where you're going with this. Can I ask for a clue regarding "Between the lines, find what's right"?

Feel free to ask
